# Узнать название чата по chat_id telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Я знаю, как получить id по названию открытой группы с помощью telethon. Есть возможность получить название открытой группы по её id?

Answer (score 0):

Да есть. Попробуй этот код.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel

chanPeer=PeerChannel(channel_id=chat_id)

channel_entity=client.get_entity(chanPeer)
print(channel_entity.title)
```